# Update entity field from String to List<String> in Jhipster

Tags: spring, list, entity, field, jhipster

I've searched a lot on the web but I found nothing that helps me, so I decided to try here.

I'm developing an app using Jhipster code generator. I know that an entity can be modified by using the command "**yo jhipster-entity EntityName**", using that I can choose between String, Integer, Long, Float, Double, BigDecimal and LocalDate. The problem is that I need something like a Set or List of String.

Is there any way to do that via command line?

This is my Entity "Desk":

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A Desk.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "desk")
public class Desk implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "users_on_it")
    private String usersOnIt;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "desk")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<CustomUser> users = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsersOnIt() {
        return usersOnIt;
    }

    public Desk usersOnIt(String usersOnIt) {
        this.usersOnIt = usersOnIt;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUsersOnIt(String usersOnIt) {
        this.usersOnIt = usersOnIt;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Desk name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<CustomUser> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public Desk users(Set<CustomUser> customUsers) {
        this.users = customUsers;
        return this;
    }

    public Desk addUsers(CustomUser customUser) {
        this.users.add(customUser);
        customUser.setDesk(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Desk removeUsers(CustomUser customUser) {
        this.users.remove(customUser);
        customUser.setDesk(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<CustomUser> customUsers) {
        this.users = customUsers;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Desk desk = (Desk) o;
        if (desk.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), desk.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Desk{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", usersOnIt='" + getUsersOnIt() + "'" +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Jhipster generated a Set field (Set of CustomUser) by relationship, but the field I need isn't related with other entities.

Giving thanks in advice for your precious time, Manuel.

Comment: No it's not yet possible, there's a feature request opened for this: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/issues/129

Answer (score 0):

Depending on jdl document [here](https://jhipster.github.io/jdl/#annexes) the collection type for field is not handled yet.

I guess you already think of creating an title object and create one-to-many relation with document right?

Comment: I thought that but I don't think that could be a valid solution because the field I need has no relationships. I could try and if it works I could remove the relationship after the generation of that new field, I don't know if it works. Tomorrow in the morning I'll do some tests and I'll let you know. Thanks for your help!